# C#.NET MVC4 - null entry for parameter of non-nullable type for a method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Within my c#.net project I am getting this error when I try to get an onClick event to begin. I think I may be missing an important assembly reference but cannot figure out why this error is occurring. The project was working fine up until recently and some modification I have made has caused this problem

**Issue**

> ### SERVER ERROR IN APPLICATION
>
> Server Error in '/' Application.

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'lat' of non-nullable type 'System.Double' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Double, Double, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String)' in 'MyDisplayTracking.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'lat' of non-nullable type 'System.Double' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Double, Double, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String)' in 'MyDisplayTracking.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

[ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'lat' of non-nullable type 'System.Double' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Double, Double, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String)' in 'MyDisplayTracking.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters]
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor.ExtractParameterFromDictionary(ParameterInfo parameterInfo, IDictionary`2 parameters, MethodInfo methodInfo) +664911
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0(ParameterInfo parameterInfo) +18
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +85
   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +217
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +78
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +133
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +237
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__20() +24
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +126
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +61
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9042429
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1016

### \

**Home controller:**

```
 public ActionResult MyStores(double lat, double lng, string storename, string city, string state, string distributor, string channels)
    {
        MyStoresModel r = new MyStoresModel();
        r.stores = new List<StoreDataModel>();
        using (DisplayTrackingEntities ctx = new DisplayTrackingEntities())
        {
```

and I am trying to call it from my Index view as follows:

```
            <input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" />
        <input type="hidden" id="lng" name="lng" />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button class="btn" onclick="return UseGPS();">Use GPS</button>
                <button class="btn" onclick="return Search();">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You wrote a book or a question?

Comment: In future using source control might help you figure out at what point you made a breaking change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the `System.ArgumentException` because you haven't assigned values to either of the hidden fields.  Your view should look something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" value="1.234" />
<input type="hidden" id="lng" name="lng" value="5.678" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could assign default values to lat & lng in your action's parameter list like this:

public ActionResult MyStores(double lat = 0.0, double lng = 0.0, string storename...

If these fields have values on the page, they'll post back and override the defaults.  If they don't have values, they'll not post back (hence the null), so the fields will retain the default.  Basically, these fields are now optional parameters.